# How do I decode ASCII data in NiFi?

Tags: ascii, apache-nifi, decode

I want to decode an ASCII string corresponding to an attachment using NiFi.
Here is an excerpt from the flow file:

```
<BinaryHexObject>01234567890ABCDEF</BinaryHexObject><BinaryDescriptionText>E-mail Attachment</BinaryDescriptionText><BinaryLocationURI>Message.msg</BinaryLocationURI>
```

The generic hexidecimal string in **<BinaryHexObject>** corresponds to an e-mail attachment in real life.  That is what I want to decode.  Is there a certain block I can use, or is there another way to do it?  If I can't and have to go another route, I want to know that also.

Comment: It is not clear what do you need. Please edit your question and add input sample data and expected output. This could help to improve the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I added an excerpt from the flow file.  I hope that clears things up.

Comment: I think I should use the Base64EncodeContent processor to do the job.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Base64EncodeContent/index.html

Comment: this looks like hex encoding - not base64. if so - there is no built-in decoder for this. you have to use script or some command line util to decode it...

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it would help, but I ended up barking up the wrong tree.,

Comment: I think a Python script will be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help.  I think we will hold off on doing this for now; it may be more trouble than it's worth (in man-hours).